# three police; four cattle

Tags: countability, pluralia-tantum

There is a group of the nouns that have only plural form and don't have an "-s" at the end. I know three words from this group:

> people, police and cattle.

As I've already found out, we can say "two/three/... people". And now I'm interested: can we also use numbers with the rest of the words of this group?

For example:

> The murder was committed between the towns A, B and C. That's why the investigation was simultaneously assigned to all **three police**.

> There are nine big farms in the area, each of which has its own cattle. **Four cattle** are basically being raised for meat production and five for milk production.

Comment: Who says 'police' has no plural? I'd want to see 'assigned to all three police forces'.

Comment: You can't use 'cattle' like that either.

Comment: "People" is the plural of "person".

Comment: @gotube: The troube is, another plural of 'person' is 'persons'.

Comment: @TonyK Colloquially, "people" is used as the plural of "person". "Persons" is only used in highly formal situations like police reports and other legal things.

Comment: @gotube: and your point is...?

Comment: @TonyK Point is there's no "trouble" if I say "people" is the plural of "person", because *de facto*, it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, 'police' cannot be used the same way. To use a number with 'police', you will have to specify what kind of a grouping you are referring to - 3 police officers, 3 police cohorts, etc. are correct, but saying '3 police' is ambiguous. In your example, this would probably be correct:

> The murder was committed between the towns A, B and C. That's why the investigation was simultaneously assigned to all three police **stations.**

Or some similar town-level grouping of police, as town is the specified level of grouping in the sentence.

Similarly, cattle cannot be used the same way. Your example sentence is grouping the cattle by farms, and hence you have to use farms instead of cattle in your example:

> There are nine big farms in the area, each of which has its own cattle. Four farms are raising cattle for meat production and five for milk production.

Also to be noted: 4 cattle is not wrong, it just refers to 4 individual cattle, not 4 groups of cattle - similar to people, which does not fit with the grouping in your example. Police is dissimilar from people and cattle since people is the plural of person, and cattle is the plural of cattle, but police is not the plural of anything since there needs to be a grouping of the police for there to be a plural of it (police officers, stations, cohorts).

Comment: Four cattle is wrong, cattle is a mass noun (uncountable). Once you start counting, it's four head of cattle, or four herds of cattle, or three cows and a steer, etc.

Answer (score 6):

"Police" is an uncountable plural. You'd have to say, "all three police **officers**".

"Cattle" can be used countably or uncountably, as [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=three+cattle+were%2Cthree+head+of+cattle+were&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3#) shows. When you use it uncountably, "head" is the unit, as in, "four **head** of cattle".

"People" is not in this category. It's the plural of "person".

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find a few examples of sentences such as “Joanne Elliot from NSW Police media says three police entered the water to save the man,” from reputable sources such as the Australian Broadcasting Company and official reports from the government of Tasmania.  There are not many examples, and all the ones I found were from Australia.

This would be considered an error in American English.  “The police” is a mass noun, not a count noun.

Another of your examples is not quite correct.  “People” can be a plural of “person,” but there is also a word “peoples,” meaning different ethnic groups or nations, as in, “the Afghan people and all the peoples of the world.”

Most English uncountable nouns are singular, but exceptions include *scissors* and *pants*.  If we need to count them, we’d say “one pair of scissors,” or “three pairs of pants.”  Similarly, we’d usually count cattle as “two hundred head of cattle,” but there are other words for cattle that are less grammatically unusual, such as the old-fashioned word *kine*, or the more recent trend of calling cattle of all ages and sexes *cows* (which sounds wrong to me, but probably doesn’t to most younger Americans).

Comment: And to add to the person/people confusion, 'person' has the alternative plural 'persons'.

Comment: "three police entered the water..." sounds fine to my American ear. A _little_ unusual, but quite understandable as shorthand. Also, maybe Australian news outlets are better than American ones, but quoting the news here as an objective standard on grammar usage is akin to shooting yourself in the foot. So many headlines and even full articles could be simplified to "First!" for all the grammar mistakes they contain.

Answer (score 1):

CGEL (Huddleston, Pullum et al) (p 345) lists 'police' and 'cattle' as rare examples of a class of nouns it terms 'quasi-count nouns':

> [There exist] a few plural[-agreement]-only nouns that are not morphologically marked as plural:...[a] cattle, livestock, police, poultry [in the livestock sense], vermin ... [These nouns] cannot be used with low numerals, but are found with high round numerals (and hence might
> be classified as ‘quasi-count nouns’) ... [thus]
>
> - a thousand cattle [but not]
> - **∗**seven cattle [, contrast]
> - seven cows'.

[reformatted]

See the ELU thread [Is the term 'quasi-count noun {usage}' used in a grammar or articles?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385046/is-the-term-quasi-count-noun-usage-used-in-a-grammar-or-articles).

Thus the CGEL authors endorse (on descriptivist grounds) '2000 police', '10 000 cattle', but not '3 police', '17 cattle'. Workarounds are necessary: '3 police officers', '17 cows'/'16 cows and a bull'. ('Beasts' is not very common outside farming circles, and as for 'kine' and 'neats' ....)

As for 'people', in the sense of 'persons' rather than 'nation', again to be found in CGEL is:

> [Among the] few plural[-agreement]-only nouns that are not
> morphologically marked as plural are [b] 'people' and 'folk' [the
> words in this subset are not included as quasi-count nouns].

'People' in this sense is a plural-agreement-only count noun (7 people, 39 people, 2000 people); the morphologically-marked-as-plural *peoples* is not used in this sense. Perhaps countness is gradable even here; '2 people' / '3 people' would perhaps be seen as unusual.
Though CGEL doesn't mention this, I'd say 'folk' is rarely preceded by a numeral, and the morphologically marked plural form 'folks' (probably even more informal) is a synonym: 'Many folk/s ...'.